# SASS mixin to define modifier classes for various screen sizes

Tags: sass, mixins

I wish to make a mixin to produce the following result of modifier classes:

```
.text-left {
    text-align: left
}
.text-right {
    text-align: right
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center
}
.text-justify {
    text-align: justify
}
.float-left {
    float: left
}
.float-right {
    float: right
}
.float-none {
    float: none
}
.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0
}
.remove {
    display: none
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .m-text-left {
        text-align: left
    }
    .m-text-right {
        text-align: right
    }
    .m-text-center {
        text-align: center
    }
    .m-text-justify {
        text-align: justify
    }
    .m-float-left {
        float: left
    }
    .m-float-right {
        float: right
    }
    .m-float-none {
        float: none
    }
    .m-hide {
        visibility: hidden;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0
    }
    .m-remove {
        display: none
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 620px) {
    .p-text-left {
        text-align: left
    }
    .p-text-right {
        text-align: right
    }
    .p-text-center {
        text-align: center
    }
    .p-text-justify {
        text-align: justify
    }
    .p-float-left {
        float: left
    }
    .p-float-right {
        float: right
    }
    .p-float-none {
        float: none
    }
    .p-hide {
        visibility: hidden;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0
    }
    .p-remove {
        display: none
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 621px) and (max-width: 955px) {
    .t-text-left {
        text-align: left
    }
    .t-text-right {
        text-align: right
    }
    .t-text-center {
        text-align: center
    }
    .t-text-justify {
        text-align: justify
    }
    .t-float-left {
        float: left
    }
    .t-float-right {
        float: right
    }
    .t-float-none {
        float: none
    }
    .t-hide {
        visibility: hidden;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0
    }
    .t-remove {
        display: none
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 956px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .l-text-left {
        text-align: left
    }
    .l-text-right {
        text-align: right
    }
    .l-text-center {
        text-align: center
    }
    .l-text-justify {
        text-align: justify
    }
    .l-float-left {
        float: left
    }
    .l-float-right {
        float: right
    }
    .l-float-none {
        float: none
    }
    .l-hide {
        visibility: hidden;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0
    }
    .l-remove {
        display: none
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .d-text-left {
        text-align: left
    }
    .d-text-right {
        text-align: right
    }
    .d-text-center {
        text-align: center
    }
    .d-text-justify {
        text-align: justify
    }
    .d-float-left {
        float: left
    }
    .d-float-right {
        float: right
    }
    .d-float-none {
        float: none
    }
    .d-hide {
        visibility: hidden;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0
    }
    .d-remove {
        display: none
    }
}
```

I came up with this mixin, which depends on the [media mixin from Neat](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/blob/bff08df8fec78f1186428aaea49ab79f3a87b398/app/assets/stylesheets/grid/_media.scss) by thoughtbot.

```
@mixin respond($responsive-classes) {
    @each $responsive-class in $responsive-classes {
        @each $selector, $rules in $responsive-class {
            $screen: null;
            @if (type-of($rules) == "list") {
                @each $rule in $rules {
                    @include rule-loop($screen, $selector, $rule);
                }
            } @else {
                @include rule-loop($screen, $selector, $rules);
            }
        }
    }
    @each $screen, $query in (
        m: max-width $small-screen,                                 // Phones
        p: min-width $small-screen + 1 max-width $medium-screen,    // Phones to Phablets
        t: min-width $medium-screen + 1 max-width $large-screen,    // Phablets to Tablets
        l: min-width $large-screen + 1 max-width $wide-screen - 1,  // Tablets to Desktops
        d: min-width $wide-screen) {                                // Desktops
        @include media($query, $grid-columns) {
            @each $responsive-class in $responsive-classes {
                @each $selector, $rules in $responsive-class {
                    @if (type-of($rules) == "list") {
                        @each $rule in $rules {
                            @include rule-loop($screen, $selector, $rule);
                        }
                    } @else {
                        @include rule-loop($screen, $selector, $rules);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@mixin rule-loop($screen, $selector, $rules) {
    @each $property, $values in $rules {
        $list: false;
        @if (type-of($values) == "list") { $list: true; }
        @include value-loop($values, $screen, $selector, $property, $list);
    }
}

@mixin value-loop($values, $screen, $selector, $property, $list) {
    @each $value in $values {
        @if $list {
            @if $screen == null {
                .#{$selector}-#{$value} {
                    #{$property}: #{$value};
                }
            } @else {
                .#{$screen}-#{$selector}-#{$value} {
                    #{$property}: #{$value};
                }
            }
        } @else {
            @if $screen == null {
                .#{$selector} {
                    #{$property}: #{$value};
                }
            } @else {
                .#{$screen}-#{$selector} {
                    #{$property}: #{$value};
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
@include respond((
  (text: (text-align: (left, right, center, justify))),
  (float: (float: (left, right, none))),
  (hide: ((visibility: hidden), (overflow: hidden), (max-height: 0))),
  (remove: (display: none))
    ));
```

It got way too complex at some point and I believe it's quite wet. Perhaps someone would be able to dry it out, or have me make a more dry approach to produce the same results? I need the mixin to be dynamic in order to be able to produce more modifier classes, should I need to do so, in the future.

The grid variables are as follows:

```
// Grid system
$grid-columns: 12;
$sidebar-columns: 4;
$max-width: 1170px;

// Breakpoints
$small-screen: 480px;
$medium-screen: 620px;
$large-screen: 955px;
$wide-screen: 1200px;
```

You may use `#{$query}` instead of `media($query, $grid-columns)` without the Neat mixin. I only used it so that the media queries would combine.

Comment: It does not compile. Please provide also the values of `*-screen` variables and the `media` mixin. Tried on [SassMeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/).

Comment: @fracz Just updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following mixin that gave me the appropriate results.

Mixin:

```
// Class Parser
@mixin parse($modifier-classes, $screen) {
    @each $selector, $rules in $modifier-classes {
        @each $property, $values in $rules {
            @if (type-of($values) == "list") {
                @each $value in $values {
                    .#{$screen}#{$selector}-#{$value} {
                        #{$property}: $value;
                    }
                }
            } @else {
                .#{$screen}#{$selector} {
                    #{$property}: $values;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Modifier Classes Mixin
@mixin respond($modifier-classes) {
    @include parse($modifier-classes, null);                            // All
    @each $screen, $query in (
        m: max-width $small-screen,                                     // Phones
        p: min-width $small-screen + 1 max-width $medium-screen - 1,    // Phones to Phablets
        t: min-width $medium-screen max-width $large-screen,            // Phablets to Tablets
        l: min-width $large-screen + 1 max-width $wide-screen - 1,      // Tablets to Desktops
        d: min-width $wide-screen) {                                    // Desktops
        @include media($query) {
            @include parse($modifier-classes, #{$screen}-);
        }
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
// Modifier Classes Variable
$modifier-classes: (
        text:   ( text-align:   (left, right, center, justify)  ),
        float:  ( float:        (left, right, none)             ),
        hide:   ( position:     absolute,
                  overflow:     hidden,
                  clip:         rect(0 0 0 0),
                  height: 1px,  width: 1px,
                  margin: -1px, padding: 0, border:0            ),
        remove: ( display:      none                            )
);

// Modifier Classes Added to CSS
@include respond($modifier-classes);
```

Gives the following result:

```
.text-left {
    text-align: left
}
.text-right {
    text-align: right
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center
}
.text-justify {
    text-align: justify
}
.float-left {
    float: left
}
.float-right {
    float: right
}
.float-none {
    float: none
}
.hide {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0
}
.remove {
    display: none
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .m-text-left {
        text-align: left
    }
    .m-text-right {
        text-align: right
    }
    .m-text-center {
        text-align: center
    }
    .m-text-justify {
        text-align: justify
    }
    .m-float-left {
        float: left
    }
    .m-float-right {
        float: right
    }
    .m-float-none {
        float: none
    }
    .m-hide {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        margin: -1px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0
    }
    .m-remove {
        display: none
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 619px) {
    .p-text-left {
        text-align: left
    }
    .p-text-right {
        text-align: right
    }
    .p-text-center {
        text-align: center
    }
    .p-text-justify {
        text-align: justify
    }
    .p-float-left {
        float: left
    }
    .p-float-right {
        float: right
    }
    .p-float-none {
        float: none
    }
    .p-hide {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        margin: -1px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0
    }
    .p-remove {
        display: none
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 620px) and (max-width: 955px) {
    .t-text-left {
        text-align: left
    }
    .t-text-right {
        text-align: right
    }
    .t-text-center {
        text-align: center
    }
    .t-text-justify {
        text-align: justify
    }
    .t-float-left {
        float: left
    }
    .t-float-right {
        float: right
    }
    .t-float-none {
        float: none
    }
    .t-hide {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        margin: -1px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0
    }
    .t-remove {
        display: none
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 956px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .l-text-left {
        text-align: left
    }
    .l-text-right {
        text-align: right
    }
    .l-text-center {
        text-align: center
    }
    .l-text-justify {
        text-align: justify
    }
    .l-float-left {
        float: left
    }
    .l-float-right {
        float: right
    }
    .l-float-none {
        float: none
    }
    .l-hide {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        margin: -1px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0
    }
    .l-remove {
        display: none
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .d-text-left {
        text-align: left
    }
    .d-text-right {
        text-align: right
    }
    .d-text-center {
        text-align: center
    }
    .d-text-justify {
        text-align: justify
    }
    .d-float-left {
        float: left
    }
    .d-float-right {
        float: right
    }
    .d-float-none {
        float: none
    }
    .d-hide {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        margin: -1px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0
    }
    .d-remove {
        display: none
    }
}
```